# Making sense of Python

Tags: python

I am reading the book Programming Collective Intelligence, What exactly the following piece of python code do?

```
  # Add up the squares of all the differences 
  sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2) 
                      for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
```

I am trying to play with the examples in Java.

Prefs is a map of person to movie ratings, movie ratings is another map of names to ratings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First it constructs a list containing the results from:

```
for each item in prefs for person1:
    if that is also an item in the prefs for person2:
        find the difference between the number of prefs for that item for the two people
        and square it (Math.pow(x,2) is "x squared")
```

Then it adds those up.

Comment: Also, in a recent version of Python, you don't need the "[" and "]" outside the whole list.  If those are missing then Python won't bother to actually make the list, but will just add the values up as it calculates them.

Comment: so, this is the sum of the square of difference of common scores between the two right?

Comment: Yes (I need to add more letters here before I can commit).

Answer (score 2):

This might be a *little* more readable if the call to pow were replaced with an explicit use of '**' exponentiation operator:

```
sum_of_squares=sum([(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item])**2
                   for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
```

Lifting out some invariants also helps readability:

```
p1_prefs = prefs[person1]
p2_prefs = prefs[person2]

sum_of_squares=sum([(p1_prefs[item]-p2_prefs[item])**2
                      for item in p1_prefs if item in p2_prefs])
```

Finally, in recent versions of Python, there is no need for the list comprehension notation, sum will accept a generator expression, so the []'s can also be removed:

```
sum_of_squares=sum((p1_prefs[item]-p2_prefs[item])**2
                      for item in p1_prefs if item in p2_prefs)
```

Seems a bit more straightforward now.

Ironically, in pursuit of readability, we have also done some performance optimization (two endeavors that are usually mutually exclusive):

- lifted invariants out of the loop
- replaced the function call pow with inline evaluation of '**' operator
- removed unnecessary construction of a list

Is this a great language or what?!

Answer (score 1):

```
01 sum_of_squares =
02 sum(
03  [
04      pow(
05         prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],
06         2
07      ) 
08    for
09       item
10    in
11       prefs[person1]
12    if
13       item in prefs[person2]
14  ]
15 )
```

Sum (line 2) a list, that consists of the values computed in lines 4-7 for each 'item' defined in the list specified on line 11 which the condition on line 13 holds true for.

Answer (score 0):

It computes the sum of the squares of the difference between `prefs[person1][item]` and `prefs[person2][item]`, for every `item` in the `prefs` dictionary for `person1` that is also in the `prefs` dictionary for `person2`.

In other words, say both `person1` and `person2` have a rating for the film [Ratatouille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratatouille_(film)), with `person1` rating it 5 stars, and `person2` rating it 2 stars.

```
prefs[person1]['Ratatouille'] = 5
prefs[person2]['Ratatouille'] = 2
```

The square of the difference between `person1`'s rating and `person2`'s rating is `3^2 = 9`.

<s>It's probably computing some kind of [Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).</s>